# What is the difference of λx. x (λy. y) and (λx. x) (λy. y)

Tags: lambda-calculus

> Lambda expressions extend as far to the right as possible. For example
> λx. x λy. y is the same as λx. x (λy. y), and is not the same as (λx. x) (λy. y).

I cant see the difference, in both cases it seems that (λy. y) is applied to (λx. x) reducing to (λy. y), isnt this the case?

What is the reduction of the first case so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cant see the difference, in both cases it seems that (λy. y) is applied to (λx. x) reducing to (λy. y), isnt this the case?

I think you meant to write "(λx. x) is applied to (λy. y)", rather than the reverse. (We say that a function is "applied" to its argument, not the other way around.)

But to answer your question — no. The formula λ*x*.*x* λ*y*.*y* means λ*x*.*x*(λ*y*.*y*), which means λ*x*.(*x*(λ*y*.*y*)); that is, it's a function that takes a parameter *x* (which is a function), applies that parameter to the identity function λ*y*.*y*, and returns the result.

I see that you know Python, so in Python terms:

- Let `identity` be the function defined as

  ```py
  def identity(y):
      return y
  ```

  Then λ*y*.*y* means `identity`.
- λ*x*.*x*(λ*y*.*y*) means

  ```py
  lambda x: x(identity)
  ```

  So, for example, (λ*x*.*x*(λ*y*.*y*))(λ*t*.3) is

  ```py
  (lambda x: x(identity))(lambda t: 3)
  ```

  which evaluates to `3`.
- (λ*x*.*x*)(λ*y*.*y*) means

  ```py
  identity(identity)
  ```

  which, as you say, reduces to just `identity`; so ((λ*x*.*x*)(λ*y*.*y*))(λ*t*.3) is

  ```py
  (identity(identity))(lambda t: 3)
  ```

  which evaluates to `(lambda t: 3)`.
- λ*x*.*x* λ*y*.*y* means λ*x*.*x*(λ*y*.*y*), **not** (λ*x*.*x*)(λ*y*.*y*).

Comment: So if I get it right the first one is in its normal form, I need an argument to to apply it

Comment: Also thanks for correcting me I aways thought that values were applied to functions vilut is the inverse, thanks!